# Calling same api from multiple fragments

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-livedata

I am using mvvm in my android project. I have to call same API from different ui fragments. According to mvvm there is one view model for for one ui. So should I have to copy my code for api code for each ui fragment?

Answer (score 0):

No.You must create a Repository class and add the function to call the API in this repository class now link you repository class with your view model.Now whenever you want to call API just call the function you wrote in the view model in whichever fragment you want. Don't forget to connect your fragment to the view model

Answer (score 0):

Just attach the viewmodel to your new fragment same as you attached with previous fragment.
In MVVM view model doesn't care who made the request and doesn't contain any reference to view components. Which makes it reusable in app and is beauty of MVVM.